# How to remove username in the Joomla registration

Tags: overrides, registration, 3.5.1

I have gone through some Q&A but not sure how to do it. I want the registration form will be only--

Name
Email
Password
Re-type Password

I have installed Authentication - EMail and Authentication - Awo Email Login.Then how to do next? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need to install third-party plugins for this.

Just create template override for com_users registration and there you can hide username field and copy email field value into this field on form submit.

so this is gone be pure Joomla solution,

---

do it like this:

1. go to http://katalog.dev/administrator/index.php?option=com_templates&view=templates
2. open template needed
3. "Create override" tab => com_users => registration

Now you have override. Next step is code changes

4. [See changes needed to files here](https://gist.github.com/alex7r/8baccd234c6c9a009042aa1219c99c64/revisions?diff=unified) at gist.github (you need changes from "alex7r revised this gist")

**Note** that file name is not `com_users_registration_default.php` but `com_users/registration/default.php`. And full path is `/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_users/registration/default.php`

Comment: Can you tell me more in detail? like where is the file and what codes to write. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did my extended answer helped?

Comment: I kept clicking "registration" twice, and don't change the codes yet. Will it hurt?

Comment: no, not at all. it may result at creating second batch of file postfixed with current date, just delete those.

Comment: Anyway, I have deleted those two files with date name in the file managers. Do you mean to add the first codes in the com_users_registration_default.php? and no about com_users_registration_complete.php? and how about the second default.php codes? Then I will have -- Name, Email, Password, Retype Password? Thanks a lot.

Comment: didn't quite understand your comment. in my gist there was initial file state(not modified) and revision that modifies code and do what you need. but in the end with standard template you can just copy code from com_users_registration_default.php into templates/html/com_users/registration/default.php . if you use some 3rd party template just copy changes from revision 2

Comment: You provided three files codes, First file with codes in green background are to add in the original files. And the other two codes are the original standard codes, correct? So complete.php doesn't get changed?

Comment: yes, 120% correct )

Comment: Hi Alexandr, in your codes it shows + at the front of every line, should I delete them and change to { for every one? Thank you so much.

Comment: I added 14-28 lines in the default.php but it doesn't change. I also deleted +

Comment: Can you provide me with URL? Are you sure you changed files in correct template?

Comment: Yes, I can also provide you the back-end link. Please give me your email. Thanks Alex so much.

Comment: kosarev@joomplace.com

Comment: I just sent you, please see your email. Thank you so much. Please don't ruin the files since I don't have backup and some are live sites.

Comment: As I wrote in email - the issue there is com_hikashop registration is used instead of com_users

Comment: I saw you changed com_hikashop/../ with two files, custom_fields and registration. The original files are written as with custom_field_bootstrap and registration_bootstrap. No change in the com_users folders. Correct?

Comment: the only file changed is registration.php in com_hikashop